# Custom WPF TabItem Style has Ghost line?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

I am creating a custom styling for tabitem and have it almost exactly how I want, I just have one small issue remaining.  This is what the control looks like rendered:

[image: tab rendering]

What I would like is for the primary color to be continuous and the black border to go around the edges of both the tab and the content.  Right now the black border is correct, but there is a faint white/gray line that still separates the tab from the content and for the life of me I don't know where it's coming from.

It appears to be an inner glow on the content border or something, but I don't know why that would be there.  I have opened the template in blend and as far as I can tell it's just a border for the host.  When I create another border (the red area) I don't see the glow.

I have also tried to make the active tab have a -2 margin on the right instead of -1.  This removes (covers) the white line, but then the black border has 2 extra pixels sticking out instead of merging cleanly with the content border.

Here are the relevant portions of the internal window code:

```
<Window.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF4678A5" x:Key="br_Blue1" />
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3C678E" x:Key="br_Blue2" />
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF325676" x:Key="br_Blue3" />
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF28455F" x:Key="br_Blue4" />
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF1E3447" x:Key="br_Blue5" />
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF142330" x:Key="br_Blue6" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="br_DialogBase" Color="#FFF0F0F0" />

    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                    <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="20,0,0,-1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ContentSource="Header" />
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-10,0,-1,-1" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="25,15,15,15" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Padding="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <TabItem Background="{StaticResource br_Blue6}" Header="Test6">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource br_Blue6}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Background="{StaticResource br_Blue5}" Header="Test5" />
    <TabItem Background="{StaticResource br_Blue4}" Header="Test4" />
    <TabItem Background="{StaticResource br_Blue3}" Header="Test3" />
    <TabItem Background="{StaticResource br_Blue2}" Header="Test2" />
    <TabItem Background="{StaticResource br_Blue1}" Header="Test1">
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource br_Blue1}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="DarkRed" Margin="20" BorderThickness="1" />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok so weird.  I did a little tinkering with the dialog and now the line is gone...  All I did was set explicit height on the border in the template, set explicit width on the tab item via setter, gave the border a name and make the TargetName for the margin setting in triggers to be the border.  However I tried to back out of each of these changes and I still don't see any line...

Comment: I'm happy it's gone but if anyone can shed any light on why for my learning purposes I will mark as answer...

Comment: So if you go look at the [default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `{x:Type TabControl}` (not the item), ya see the `ContentPresenter` in there sitting in the embedded `x:Name="Border"`? Just pull off the `BorderThickness` on there.

Comment: I do see that but I can also set BorderThickness=0 on the TabControl and it gets rid of the border altogether.  I want the black border, just not the 'glow' on the bottom and left sides that I was seeing before...

Comment: Follow your 'glow' up and down, it stretches the height of the control, you're still working in the item template, not the controls, your BorderThickness=0 is not hitting the object I'm talking about because it's a hard-coded property, not bound to the template.